# jquery 1.7 "on" method IE8 crashes mshtml.dll

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

As mentioned I'm using latest version of jQuery.

I simply call

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

It runs well on every browser except IE8 (not tested on IE7). 
Note I'm running Windows on Parallels Desktop on my iMac.

The crash has something to do with `mshtml.dll` as reported by IE8 Crash dialog box.

Any advice?

Check the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/kuht6/4/

Comment: Tested with both 1.7 and 1.7.1

Comment: Works for me on WIN 7 and IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

is working fine here something else could be wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/5Hhmg/

Comment: Can't find a way to reproduce. Note that the 'tr' element on which I'm binding for the click event is generated dynamically from an ajax request.

Comment: that  should not be a problem `on` takes care of dynamically generated elements.

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with the dll download it again and replace the old one

Comment: Even by disabling my Javascript code, IE8 crashes when I click on a table tr.

The HTML is quite simple. I just have an <input type="radio"> under a <form> under a <table>. If I click everywhere on the table ie8 CRASHES. 

I cannot find a way to debug.

On jsfiddle.net it is working quite well.

Comment: try accessing it with some other browser its opening fine with me